# VBA string variables does not put constant string value in string concatenating

Tags: string, vba

all. My code like this:

```
Sub mySub

Public Const strVarA As String = "AA"
Public Const strVarB As String = "BB"
Public Const strVarC As String = "CC"

Dim myStrArray() As String
Dim myString As String
myStrArray = ["strVarA", "strVarB", "strVarC"]

For i = 0 To 2
    myURL = "http://www.yahoo.com/news/" & myStrArray(i) & ".html" <--- Here, wrong
    '//do something.
Next i

End Sub
```

My purpose is in the For loop, myStrArray(0) should put its constant value "AA" in the URL,
like this:

```
"http://www.yahoo.com/news/AA.html"
```

because the URL use "AA" in its link. But the code always put "strVarA", like this:

```
"http://www.yahoo.com/news/strVarA.html"
```

Similar as when loop to myStrArray(1), it should put "BB" in URL, myStrArray(2) should put "CC" in URL. I tried many ways, no luck. Does somebody have experience and suggestions about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code :

```
Sub mySub()

 Const strVarA As String = "AA"
 Const strVarB As String = "BB"
 Const strVarC As String = "CC"

'Dim myStrArray() As String
Dim myString As String
myStrArray = Array("strVarA", "strVarB", "strVarC")

For i = LBound(myStrArray) To UBound(myStrArray)
    myURL = "http://www.yahoo.com/news/" & myStrArray(i) & ".html"
    '//do something.
Next i

End Sub
```

[image]

**Updated after comments**

```
Sub mySub()

    Dim myStrArray As Variant
    myStrArray = Array("AA", "BB", "CC")

    For i = LBound(myStrArray) To UBound(myStrArray)
        myurl = "http://www.yahoo.com/news/" & myStrArray(i) & ".html"
        MsgBox myurl
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Santosh, thanks for your quick reply. But I tried, no luck, the result is same as mine. The point is how to convert a string to a variable with the same name. For my code, that is, convert string "strVarA" to variable strVarA. That will work, I already tried:

    myURL = "http://www.yahoo.com/news/" & strVarA & ".html"

It gave me:

    myURL = "http://www.yahoo.com/news/AA.html"

which is correct URL.

Comment: Santosh, actually I put all constant statement in a module called mConstants within the same workbook.

Comment: Santosh, I read your updated code. Unfortunately, I must use string "strVarA", "strVarB", "strVarC" in myStrArray, because they are downloaded from web page. The point is they have one to one alliance name "AA", "BB", "CC" which are used for further browering. It is impossible to manually transfer strings "strVarA", "strVarB",... to "AA", "BB", ... because they have hundereds of strings.

Comment: That's why I use constant statements to define all strings to their one-to-one constant values.

Comment: `Const strVarA As String = "AA"
Const strVarB As String = "BB"
Const strVarC As String = "CC"

Sub mySub()

    Dim myString As String
    myStrArray = Array("strVarA", "strVarB", "strVarC")

    For i = LBound(myStrArray) To UBound(myStrArray)
        myURL = "http://www.yahoo.com/news/" & getValue(myStrArray(i)) & ".html"
        MsgBox myURL
        '//do something.
    Next i

End Sub

Function getValue(ByVal str As String) As String
    Select Case str
    Case "strVarA"
        getValue = strVarA
    Case "strVarB"
        getValue = strVarB
    End Select
End Function` Try this.

Comment: Santoch, your last code works immediately, thank you so much!!

Comment: @JimXie Please close the question by accepting the answer. Welcome :)